# How can I structure a self-contained module in Lua?

Tags: module, lua, require

I'm making a Lua library for Love2D, which contains quite a bit of internal sub-modules, class files, and the like.

What I'm doing now looks like this:

File `./libname/init.lua`

```
lib.prefix = (...):match("(.-)[^%.]+$") .. "libname."
lib = {}

lib.class = require(lib.prefix .. "lib.class")
lib.types.Blah = require(lib.prefix .. "types.Blah")

return lib
```

File `./libname/types/Blah.lua`

```
local Blah = lib.class()
...
return Blah
```

Except the thing here is that lib is a global, and if I make it into a local, I cannot properly structure the submodules like `Blah`, because they no longer have access to the `lib` table.

This is obviously a stripped down example, but I think it demonstrates my problem well - I would like to make the `lib` table local, and return it, so that inclusion of the library goes like `lib = require "libs.libname"`, rather than have the whole thing imported into the global scope when I require the module itself. Is it possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I made a guide for this very concept. You can find it here:

http://kiki.to/blog/2014/03/30/a-guide-to-authoring-lua-modules/

To solve the specific problem that you mention in your question, I would use 3 files: `core.lua` to share the state, the "real files" which change the core, and `init` to tie everything up.

`./libname/core.lua` is where `lib` is defined, as a local bar. It does not define `lib.types`. It "sets the ground up" with utilities that other files might want to use, like setting up a prefix or a utility `class`.

```
local lib = {}

lib.prefix = (...):match("(.-)[^%.]+$") .. "libname."

lib.class = require(lib.prefix .. "lib.class")

return lib
```

The 'regular files', like `./libname/types/Blah.lua`, use those utilities, but don't modify lib at all:

```
local lib = require 'core' -- or libname.core or using the current_folder trick

local Blah = lib.class()
...
return Blah
```

`init.lua` binds everything together:

```
local lib = require 'core' -- or libname.core or current_folder trick

lib.types.Blah = require(lib.prefix .. "types.Blah")

return lib
```

The "current folder trick" mentioned in the comments is here: http://kiki.to/blog/2014/04/12/rule-5-beware-of-multiple-files/#the-current_folder-trick

Comment: Looks like a good guide, but I don't see it addressing my problem - letting interdependent submodules access the master module table without putting it in a global. I could, say, strip `"lib.mymodule.submodule.a"` down to `"lib.mymodule"`, but I have to tweak the require code for every single file(or at least depth when it comes to a deeper fs hierarchy), which I honestly don't want to do. I ended up just putting the module table into `package.loaded["__mymodule"]` and requiring that internally.

Comment: I can't say I like the solution, but it doesn't seem like there are any other good alternatives, or at least, I have not seen any so far. Likewise, Deduplicator has not provided me with any example of how what he mentions solves my problems, and neither does your otherwise good article.

Comment: My apologies, I thought you were looking for general guidance, not a solution to your specific problem. I have updated my answer with the way I would solve your issue.

Comment: Hmm, this looks pretty good, but I don't really want to use the current_folder trick in every file, because it means a different line for at least every different depth in the hierarchy, that has to be updated whenever I move the files. I really like the idea of your solution + putting the module table in `package.loaded["__mymodule"]`... I just don't know if it's an okay solution, because I sometimes have huge anxiety problems and it feels sorta hacky. I mean, it's unlikely that someone would create a module called __mymodule/__whatever, but still...

Comment: Maybe I'm just overthinking this :/

Comment: Having to manually change files when I move them around has never incommoded me, since I do libraries with a small number of files (or I split into several libraries). You have to draw the line somewhere. You could add variables to `lib` (`lib.foo_path`, `lib.bar_path`) and use those on the files. But you would still have issues if you wanted to rename those vars to something else (a good editor could search/replace in files though).

Comment: Also, I don't think you must use `package.loaded` at all. If someone requires two packages named the same way, that's their responsibility, not your lib's. It's like a car builder worrying about someone not eating healthily inside the car. I am pretty sure you can let that one go. Good luck with your anxiety problems.

Comment: Hmm, alright, thanks for the advice. I think I'll go with my solution without worrying about it being somehow worse than what other people would do. I'll accept your answer though, since it's the 'usual' solution :P

Answer (score 1):

Let's take the relevant [paragraph from the documentation](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-require):

> #### require (modname)
>
> [...]
>
> Once a loader is found, `require` calls the loader with two arguments: `modname` and an extra value dependent on how it got the loader. (If the loader came from a file, this extra value is the file name.) If the loader returns any non-nil value, require assigns the returned value to `package.loaded[modname]`. If the loader does not return a non-nil value and has not assigned any value to `package.loaded[modname]`, then require assigns true to this entry. In any case, require returns the final value of `package.loaded[modname]`.

So, the way to go for a module with such recursive dependencies is:

1. Get the module name `modname` (first unnamed var-arg argument)
2. Load modules needed for basic initializing
3. Return if the module was fully set-up in 2 (recursive call)
4. Set up the module-table under `package.loaded[modname]`
5. Set up enough scaffolding to start the sub-modules
6. `require` the sub-modules
7. Do the rest of the modules setup.
8. Return (No need to return anything due to step 4).

```
local _M, modname = {}, {...}[1]
local sub = require(modname..".sub")
if package.loaded[modname] then return end
package.loaded[modname] = _M
-- Populate _M with everything needed to set up more modules
_M.X = require(modname..".X")
--Do the rest of this modules setup and that's it
--return
```

That allows you to not create any globals at all, as is proper for modern modules.

---

If you do not need any submodules while setting up the main-module, consider using on-demand-loading instead:

```
setmetatable(_M, {__index =
  function(t, k)
    t[k] = require(modname.."."..k)
    return t[k]
  end})
```

---

Should your module only be structured into submodules for external consumption, you could put it all in the main-module and let it register the appropriate member-tables as sub-modules in their own right (See step 2).
In that case, the sub-module loaders would only `require` the main-module and return nothing.

Comment: I see, this is helpful, I now know where to look. Do you have, or could write, some simple examples of how to execute said steps? I hate to say it but I don't really have a clue from your answer or the documentation.

Comment: Added example, one line for steps 1 to 5, none for step 6

Comment: I assume I put that code in `init.lua` for my module directory, right? Also, I primarily use Love2D, which I assume does some setup for me, and I find that using just Lua, I had to add `./?/init.lua` to my `package.path`. And I assume that with this setup, I'll be doing `require "module.required_submodule"` inside the submodules, right?

Comment: Alsooo... (pardon the comment/question count), how would I deal with relative requires in that case? Say, I could require `src.module.required_submodule` from another submodule, but what if I want the way the module works to be independent on whether its directory is placed in `src` or `lib` or `that_dumb_module`?

Comment: @Asmageddon: Look at [`string.gsub`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-string.gsub), you can use it, with the proper pattern and options for exactly one replacement, to remove any number of sub-module-specifiers from the module name, and replace them with anything you want.

Comment: Oh. You mean I could do something like setting `package.loaded["src.engine.modname"]` but also `package.loaded["just_name_of_my_mod"]` and then `require "just_name_of_my_mod"` from the submodules?

Comment: That would be one way to go about it, if you can guarantee the module is first loaded by canonical name (Take a look at all of `package`, too). Still, better to require either modules of known name, or modules with known relative name.

Comment: So something like manually putting my submodules in the `package.loaded` table, and then requiring them by the names I use there? What if there's an actual module file that goes by the name of what I use? How do I deal with that?

Comment: Alright, I settled on using `package.loaded["__mymodname"]` and then requiring that from submodules. Is this an at least relatively elegant solution?

Comment: I would really get the modname, and then use `string.gsub` with a single replacement to build the relative package names for `require`. If you use a special symbol which is not enough for `require` to find the module, you must manually manage dependencies, which is onerous and error-prone at best.

Comment: Yeah, but what do I do with the replaced name? Put it in a global? Avoiding polluting the global scope is sort of what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: ?? What do you mean, replaced name? All modules only use their proper name to get to `require` related modules by their own proper names. That's all.

Comment: Uhh, ok, I'm a bit lost now, I'm sorry for being a bother x.x I think I got now what you meant. You meant to do something like `require(modtable.prefix .. ".submodule")`, right? I already do that inside `init.lua`, what I mean is, how do I let the submodules access the master module table if it's not placed inside a global?

Comment: @Asmageddon: The first argument to each module is its name. As said, you just strip the unique suffix, append any other suffix as needed, and get that modules table with `require` (not directly from `package.loaded`). The modules table under `package.loaded[modname]` is the one and only "global" a module should have.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60172/discussion-between-asmageddon-and-deduplicator).